# Access to an enum before authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an account request form (before authentication) which should display the list of countries (ISO)
I have this list in an enum but I can't access it as I have neither been authorised nor have a controller that "provides" this enumeration

in my view :

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;  display: flex;justify-content: 
left;margin-bottom:0;">
            <label style=" color:white;font-size:12px;margin-right: 10px;" 
for="countryInput"
                   th:text="#{modif.country}"></label>
            <select th:name="country"
                    type="text" th:field="*{country}" class="form-control" 
id="countryInput"
                    th:errorclass="invalid"
                    th:placeholder="#{modif.country}"
                    style="width: 200px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0;">
                <option th:each="country :${T(fr.model.enumeration.Country).values()}"
                        th:value="${country}" th:text="${country}"></option>
            </select>
            <div th:errors="*{country}" style="color: red">
                Error
            </div>
        </div>
```

the enum :

```
package fr.model.enumeration;

public enum Country {
France,
Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, AmericanSamoa,
Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, Antarctica, ...
}
```

i get this error :
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'country' available as request attribute

this makes total sense to me but I want to be able to use this list without having to be authenticated

thank you for your concern

Comment: i tried some things in my security config, like add in antMatchers the path of the enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with authentication/authorization. The error "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'country' available as request attribute" indicates that it's a problem with Spring binding. I think the problem is not in the Enum, but in the select:

```
 <select th:name="country" type="text" th:field="*{country}" class="form-control" id="countryInput" th:errorclass="invalid" th:placeholder="#{modif.country}" style="width: 200px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0;">
```

How to check if the problem is in the select and not the Enum? Remove/comment the HTML option element, and you should see exactly the same error. If that's the case here goes my solution:

You are using **th:field="*{country}"**, which is used along with **th:object**.

If you have a controller that points to this view and want to use **th:object**, then you need to include th:object in your HTML form and add the object you want to use in the controller model.

If you don't have a controller or something to inject the object, remove the **th:field** and everything related to object binding from your select. If this is the case your probably don't even need the **th:field**. In that case you'll have something like this:

```html
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;  display: flex;justify-content: left;margin-bottom:0;">
<label style="color:white;font-size:12px;margin-right: 10px;" for="countryInput" th:text="#{modif.country}"></label>
<select class="form-control" id="countryInput" style="width: 200px;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:0;">
    <option th:each="country :${T(fr.model.enumeration.Country).values()}" th:value="${country}" th:text="${country}"></option>
</select>
</div>
```

In this last scenario you won't have the Spring binding. You need to define whether or not you want to use objects binding. If you don't use object binding, you won't be able to use things like th:errors or th:errorclass, but this desition is up to you and what you are trying to achieve. If YOU DO want to use object binding, you should use a controller class.

Comment: if i remove : the th:field all the *{country} references and the option i have no error (but nothing working neither). if i leave the option but no the *{country} references, i keep receiving the error.
i confirm i don't have a controller for this view
i'll say here if i find something solving my issue.


thanks

Comment: With the first thing you did, removeing the th:field, you need to remove it from the select and the div tih the th:errors="*{country}". Don't touch the options, because the country you are referencing in the options tags is differente that the country used in the select tag. Those are two different java objects and you are using the same name for both, don't get confused about that. Just leave the options, and remove the *{country} references. When you do that, what's the error you are receiving?

Comment: thank you for ur time 
i receive this errors :
- Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(fr.model.enumeration.Country).values()" 
- EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'fr.model.enumeration.Country'

i think the "no controller" option is a bad idea of mine